# IntegrityError at /admin/images/images/add/ NOT NULL constraint failed: images_images.user_id

Tags: python, django, web-applications

I have encouter these errors when working
on a project for uploading image from userinterface and filter with user:

> IntegrityError at /admin/images/images/add/
> NOT NULL constraint failed: images_images.user_id

> Request URL:   http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/images/images/add/
> Django Version: 3.1.2
> Exception Type: IntegrityError
> Exception Value:
> NOT NULL constraint failed: images_images.user_id
> Exception Location: C:\Users\Jameskumar haobam\Envs\clone2\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py, line 413, in execute
> Python Executable:  C:\Users\Jameskumar haobam\Envs\clone2\Scripts\python.exe
> Python Version: 3.8.5
> Python Path:
> ['C:\Users\Jameskumar haobam\Desktop\web dev '
> 'related\Django-project\clone',
> 'C:\Users\Jameskumar haobam\Envs\clone2\Scripts\python38.zip',
> 'c:\python\python38\DLLs',
> 'c:\python\python38\lib',
> 'c:\python\python38',
> 'C:\Users\Jameskumar haobam\Envs\clone2',
> 'C:\Users\Jameskumar haobam\Envs\clone2\lib\site-packages']
> Server time:    Mon, 12 Oct 2020 12:18:10 +0000

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .models import Images
from .form import ImageForm
@login_required
def show_all_images(req):
    all_images = Images.objects.all()
    context = {
    'images':all_images,
    }
    return render(req,"imagesapp/showimages.html",context)

def upload_image(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
    
        uploaded=ImageForm(data=request.POST,files=request.FILES)
        if uploaded.is_valid():
            uploaded.save()
            
            return redirect('show_all_images')  
    else:
        up=ImageForm()    
        
        return render(request,"imagesapp/upload.html",{"up":up})
```

**form.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Images

class  ImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
     class Meta:
           model = Images
           fields=('title','image','user')
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Images(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank = False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    about_image = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank = True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="Images")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: Can you add a more detailed description of what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I have working on a django project to upload images form the User  by login  and to display the images filter with the logged in user...but i was stuck when i add ForeignKey feild in the Model...and i got the above error ...please slove it for me

Answer (score 0):

Update forms and views files as below.
in view.py change is

```
uploaded=ImageForm(data=request.POST, files=request.FILES,)
```

to

```
uploaded=ImageForm(data=request.POST, files=request.FILES,  request=request)
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Images

class  ImageForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['commit'] = False
        obj = super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.request:
            obj.user = self.request.user
        obj.save()
        return obj
    
     class Meta:
           model = Images
           fields=('title','image','user')
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .models import Images
from .form import ImageForm
@login_required
def show_all_images(req):
    all_images = Images.objects.all()
    context = {
    'images':all_images,
    }
    return render(req,"imagesapp/showimages.html",context)

def upload_image(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
    
        uploaded=ImageForm(data=request.POST, files=request.FILES,  request=request)
        if uploaded.is_valid():
            uploaded.save()
            
            return redirect('show_all_images')  
    else:
        up=ImageForm()    
        
        return render(request,"imagesapp/upload.html",{"up":up})
```